# How do I set the height or width of TrimBar?

Tags: eclipse, e4

I have a TrimBar which configured as below

[image]

How can I change the TrimBar width or height ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TrimBar adjust to accomodate its contents.

You can add margins around the contents using CSS like:

```css
.MTrimBar ToolBar
{
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;    
}
```