# Eclipse toolbar size

Tags: eclipse

I have an issue with Eclipse toolbar. I don't know why but it is too large, how can I fix it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can fix it by css edit, you can find css at path 
ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_X.X.X_V.XXXX/css

```
.MPartStack {
    font-size: 11;
    swt-simple: false;
    swt-mru-visible: false;
}
```

there is an answer [How do I set the height or width of TrimBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838167/how-do-i-set-the-height-or-width-of-trimbar)
also can  help [How to change the font size of the Eclipse editor tab's title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317674/how-to-change-the-font-size-of-the-eclipse-editor-tabs-title)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Version: 2018-12  (Windows)
.**MPartStack** locate in
 C:\code\gtnexus\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.300.v20181108-1102\css\e4_default_win.css